# Most shiny area of a picture

Tags: java, image-processing

Is it possible to find the most shining object in a picture?

So let's there is a picture with a bright point. How can I find this point in the picture, for example to draw a circle around that point?

Where can I start?

Comment: Look for blobs of white-ish pixels with little variation?

Comment: Let's say that the picture background is totally dark, black. In this case maybe i can search for white-ish pixels as you say.

Comment: This question is ill-formed. Even if you could identify a center as the center of "shiny" versus other areas, you'd still have to define where that area starts and stops.

Comment: Can you explain this maybe on an example? (this is for the first post)

Comment: Yes i need to set some value for this. I think that in this way maybe i can define a scope for the circle, the area.

Comment: Perhaps this question would get better responses at the data analysis Stack Exchange site: [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [blob detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection).

Basically, you define an NxN operator, and pass it over each pixel in the image, computing a value for each pixel based on it and its neighbors. The resulting image has the largest values at locations of interest.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a very viable solution. Maybe there are some implementations already in Java that i can use for start.

Answer (score 0):

I would say take a pass over the image computing the magnitude of the image for example sqrt(red^2+blue^2+green^2) * alpha (if alpha is a factor). That will give you a sort of "brightness" metric.

From there it depends on exactly what you want to do. If you are simply looking to circle all bright spots then circle all spots with a magnitude greater than some cutoff point.

If you are looking for simply the brightest spot that gets a bit more complicated. One way would to be to take the derivative of the image with respect to x and y. This would define boundaries for bright spots. After that you simply go within the boundary and compute the relative magnitude of it's brightness compared to other spots in the image. Then circle the one with the brightest magnitude. All this is very general because your question was general. The exact implementation depends on what exactly you are trying to do.